# How do I reload the page immediately after display this?

Tags: php

Right now after posting that text is displayed, I want to reload the page also.

This is the text that is displayed after posting:

```
echo "Tu chisme se publicó con éxito";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either via a Meta refresh http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh
or Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

you can put header('refresh: 1; URL='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); **before** the echo.

this will make your page reload in 1 second.

Comment: For some reason it didn't work. I just copy pasted it before the echo.